# Get Disk IO using libvirt java api

Tags: java, virtualization, qemu, libvirt

I am trying to measure the Disk IOPS using libvirt java api .I am not able to figure any Java API where I can get the Disk IO information for a vm usin libvirt Java api .

Has any one done similar either using Java Libvirt API or Python Libvirt API .

Virsh gives the below output

```
virsh domblklist centos7
Target     Source
------------------------------------------------
vda        /var/lib/libvirt/images/centos7.img
hda        -


virsh blkdeviotune centos7 vda
total_bytes_sec: 0
read_bytes_sec : 0
write_bytes_sec: 0
total_iops_sec : 0
read_iops_sec  : 0
write_iops_sec : 0
```

I have my VM centos running .With java api the fields for getting the block stats are

```
 public long rd_req;
    public long rd_bytes;
    public long wr_req;
    public long wr_bytes;
    public long errs;
```

What does this field signify ,are they IOPS ?

Comment: could you try to execute `virsh ....`?

Comment: as in `virsh blkdeviotune domain device` - use domblklist to find device

Comment: in java api the fields are rd_bytes,rd.req,wr.req and wr.bytes.While when I run the virsh the ouput gives me proper IOPS.

Comment: I do not understand your reply.

Comment: @ScaryWombat updated my question with more details